# Why are topical corticosteroids used in conjunction with an antiviral to treat herpes keratitis?

Tags: medications, optometry, opthalmology

Herpes simplex keratitis is a viral infection of the eye.  Topical antiviral medications are used to treat the virus.  Corticosteroids ophthalmic drops are sometimes used as well.  But corticosteroids can suppress the immune system, and drug warnings state not to use them when one has a viral infection. This seems like a contraindication, so why would steroids be used for herpes keratitis?

Comment: I altered your question to meet site standards. Revert if you disagree but it will likely be closed for personal advice request. For your case, I presume the same doctor prescribed both, right?  They likely know what they're doing. Ask them or your pharmacist. Steroids reduce inflammation and protect your tissues from damage from inflammation. They do suppress your immune system, from a little to a lot, which can allow viruses to grow (or reactivate) - but you're treating the virus with an antiviral also.